# How do I import a package from the local filesystem using dub?

Tags: d, dub

I have a project that uses dub. I want to use an external file vendored into my project, as a dependency. How do I do this? I don't want to have it in my project's `source/` dir. I don't want to add it as a dub managed dependency, but I do want to be able to just `import xxx`.

The package is this one: https://github.com/gianm/d-json , it does not use dub or have a dub.json project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative thing: make a `third_party` directory, put the file in there, then add that to the `sourcePaths` in your dub config (you'll probably specify both `["third_party", "source"]` since the default `source` will be overridden if you don't list it too.

Comment: Nice! This is easier for single-file, non-dub resources like jsonx.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the package to dub by adding a `dub.json` file in the root, with the following contents: `{"name": "jsonx"}`. Create a `source` folder, and move `jsonx.d` into it.
2. Put the folder anywhere you want, e.g. top-level next to your own project.
3. Add the following dependency to your `dub.json`:

```
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "jsonx": {"path": "../jsonx/"}
    }
```

4. You can now import the package anywhere using `import jsonx;`.

In conclusion, if your app is in a dir called `app`, your tree should look like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── dub.json
│   └── source
│       └── myapp.d
└── jsonx
    ├── dub.json
    └── source
        └── jsonx.d
```